# Location not found with Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

I have an address that is a valid address [according to the USPS](https://tools.usps.com/go/ZipLookupResultsAction!input.action?resultMode=0&companyName=&address1=1606%20ULSTER%20AVE&address2=&city=LAKE%20KATRINE&state=NY&urbanCode=&postalCode=&zip=12449)...

> 1606 ULSTER AVE, LAKE KATRINE, NY 12449

[Searching Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=1606+ULSTER+AVE,+LAKE+KATRINE,+NY+12449&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&sa=N&tab=wl&authuser=0) for this address in my browser yields the proper results. However, [Google Maps API yields](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&language=en&address=1606%20ULSTER%20AVE,%20LAKE%20KATRINE,%20NY%2012449) `ZERO_RESULTS`:

```
{
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

This is happening for about 1% of my locations. Why is the API returning separate results? How do I get it to yield the same results as the browser UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps if you were to validate/standardize the address before submitting it for Google geocoding you would get better results.  A quick Google search for "address validation" will give you a number of good tools to do that.

@geocodezip is right that when you remove the ZIP code you get a more predictable response.  That might be because the ZIP code is a numeric representation of the city/state combination and is usually regarded as a positive identifier in many tables.  However, since the ZIP code can be changed at any time by the US Postal Service, a more consistent response might be obtained (if you encounter issues) by always removing the ZIP code.  The problem with always removing the ZIP code is that you have now removed 20% of the address information that you have, and many times a ZIP code can trump a bad city/state combination and still get you valid results.

Consider the following somewhat invalid address: This fails:

```
275 north main Hollywsdfsdfsdfsdfood CA 84627
```

If you discard the ZIP code, you get nothing because 275 north main is not a valid address in "Hollywsdfsdfsdfsdfood CA"

However, if you keep the ZIP code and use that instead of the unlikely "Hollywsdfsdfsdfsdfood CA" as the city/state designator, you end up with a completely valid address in Ephraim, Utah 84627.

Here's an example on [SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com/products/single-address?street=275%20N%20Main&street2=&city=Hollywsdfsdfsdfsdfood&state=CA&zipcode=84627&address-type=us-street-components) since Google Maps was unable to handle it with the bogus city name.  The validated address is:

```
275 N Main St Ephraim UT 84627-1107
```

So, going back to the idea of address validation BEFORE geocoding, you could then put that address into [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/275+N+Main+St,+Ephraim,+UT+84627/@39.3647708,-111.5896124,1054m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x874c71934934561f:0x62049df13092a51e!8m2!3d39.3647708!4d-111.5874237?hl=en) and easily get your geocode.  Maybe even keep your current process and then just add a separate routine for the 1% that fail.

[I deal with this kind of thing every day, I work at SmartyStreets]

Comment: In some (many?) countries, the postal code is the preferred quick & easy way to find a place. As a test, go to https://www.google.com.sg/ and search for 417396. You land right at the condominium. Now try searching for "417396" via the Geocoding API -- you get zero results. The behavior through the API is not consistent with what you get searching on the website.

Comment: @10basetom You are correct.  It sounds like three different "services" are being referred to here, google search engine, google maps, and google places API.  Each one will return different results, just like if you ask three different people to tell you about the Guggenheim museum.  One might tell you which seats are best, one might tell you very accurately how to get there and one might tell you the name sounds kind of familiar but that's all they know.  The three different services being referenced here have completely distinct functions.

Comment: Jeffrey, I just realized I made a typo: "go to google.com.sg" should be "go to maps.google.com.sg". If maps.google.com.sg is using the Places API instead of the Geocoding API, then can you point to a good tutorial on doing a gmaps search using the Places API? (e.g., searching for string "417396" that would return the same location as on the website)

Comment: Jeffrey, I didn't find a good tutorial, but this was sufficient :): https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=1606+ULSTER+AVE,+LAKE+KATRINE,+NY+12449&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&sa=N&tab=wl&authuser=0) is a Places API result, not from the geocoder.

Looks like the zip code is confusing the geocoder, if I remove the zip code, it returns a result:

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=1606%20ULSTER%20AVE,%20LAKE%20KATRINE,%20NY&geocode=1

Comment: Are you saying that the familiar web front end that I've grown to love is Google Places? I suppose that would make sense why the results can possibly be different. I'm still not sure why the geocoder is getting choked up on the address though. Changing the number will yield a successful result too.

Comment: Google Maps uses many different sources for its results, among them the Google Places data and the geocoder database.  Geocoders are finicky, the data changes frequently and can be inaccurate (in this case that result is interpolated ("location_type": "RANGE_INTERPOLATED"), not sure why it doesn't work with a validated USPS zip code.